# Doubling checking my understanding of these set relations

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Just trying to make sure that my understanding of the set relations below is correct

T1 = {x $\in$ $\Delta$ | for every *y*, (x,y) $\in$ R implies y $\in$ C}
T2 = {x $\in$ $\Delta$ | there exists *y*, (x,y) $\in$ R and y $\in$ C}

$\Delta$ = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}
R = {(a,b), (c,b), (d,e)}
C = {b, e}

T1 = {e}
T2 = {a, c, e}

Or is this wrong?

Comment: Why isn't e.g. $a$ and $b$ in your set $T1$?

Answer (score 0):

Well $x\in T_1$ iff for all $y\in\Delta$ either $(x,y)\in R$ and $y\in C$ or $(x,y)\notin R$. In other words $x\notin T_1$ iff there exists $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in R$ and $y\notin C$. But because for every $(x,y)\in R$, $y\in C$ this shows that $T_1=\Delta$.

Now for the second set, it is easily seen to be $\{a,c,d\}$.

Comment: I agree with you for $T_1$, but for $T_2$, no pair of $R$ starts with a $b$.

Comment: @Demosthene, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $T_1$ as:
$$T_1=\Delta-\left\{x\in\Delta\mid\exists y,(x,y)\in R\land y\notin C\right\}$$
It is easy to see that to satisfy the first condition, $y$ has to be either $b$ or $e$, but both are in $C$ and thus violate the second condition. Therefore there is no such set and we can write:
$$T_1=\Delta-\emptyset=\Delta$$
Rewrite $T_2$ as:
$$T_2=\Delta-\left\{x\in\Delta\mid\forall y,(x,y)\notin R\lor y\notin C\right\}$$
The first condition is satisfied by $b$, $e$, $f$ and $g$, as they do not appear in first position of any pair in $R$. Furthermore, $a$, $c$ and $d$ are not in $C$, and thus satisfy neither of the two conditions, such that we can exclude them from the set. Therefore:
$$T_2=\Delta-\left\{b,e,f,g\right\}=\left\{a,c,d\right\}$$